# How to achieve this complex query with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query below to get the email of all users that have a registration in a specific conference.

```
$users = User::whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use($conferenceID) {
    $query->where('conference_id', '=', $$conferenceID);
})->get();
```

And `dd($users)` shows `array:2 [▼ 0 => "....mail.com" 1 => "....mail.com"]`. So its working fine.

But I want to get only the emails of the users that did a registration in a specific conference ($conferenceID) and this registration has 1 or more participants associated with a specific registration type.

Do you know how to properly achieve this query? I have the code below but it shows "Call to undefined relationship [Registration] on model [App\Conference]".

```
$getEmailsOfAspecificRegistrationType = 
 Conference::with('registrations', 
 'Registration.registrationTypes', 'Registration.registrationTypes.participants')
->where('id', $id)->get();
```

**Table structure and example to explain better the context:**

For example there is a conference "Conference 1" that has two registration types (rt1 and rt2). And for now there are only two registrations in the conference "Conference 1". One registration was done by Jake and other by Ben. Jake did a registration with 3 participants (him, Jane and Paul). Ben only did a registration for him. The tables structure is like below.

I want to get only the emails of the users that did a registration in the conference with id "1" and this registration has 1 or more participants associated with a specific registration type, for example "rt01". So in this case I only want to get the email of the user 1 "jakeemailtest" because is the only participant that did a registration that is associated with the registration type "rt01" because the participants Jake and Jane are associated with this registration type (as is possible to check in the participants table).

Conferentes table:

```
id         name
1            Conference 1
```

Users table:

```
id           name           email
1             Jake            jakeemailtest@test...
2             Ben             benmailtest@test...
```

registration types table:

```
id   name     conference_id
1    rt1          1
2    rt2         1
```

Participants table:

```
id     registration_id      registration_type_id      name        
1         1                        1                   Jake 
2        1                        1                    Jane
3        1                       2                     Paul
4        2                      2                      Ben
```

And the registrations table:

```
id   status                user_that_did_registration       conference_id 

1         Incomplete            1                                     1
2        Incomplete             2                                     1
```

**Relevant models for the question:**

Users model:

```
public function registrations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','user_that_did_registration');
}
```

Registration model:

```
// user that did the registration
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_that_did_registration', 'id');
}
 public function participants(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
}

public function conference(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
}
```

Conference Model:

```
 public function registrations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
}
```

Participants mode:

```
public function registration(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
}

public function registration_type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
}
```

Comment: How your models relate to each other can you include your model definitions ?

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the models and also with a example with the structure of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your schema it looks like your model definitions should look like

- User has Registrations => Registration belongs to User
- Registration has Participants => Participant belongs to Registration
- Registration Type has Participants => Participant belongs to Registration Type
- Conference Has Registration Types => Registration Type belongs to Conference
- Conference Has Registrations => Registration belongs to Conference

Considering above your Conference model should also have following mapping

```
public function registration_types(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
}
```

You could go with following to get the desired users

```
$users = User::whereHas('registrations.participants.registration_type', function ($query) use ($conference_id, $request) {
                $query->where('name', '=', $request->rype)
                      ->where('conference_id', '=', $conference_id);
            })->whereHas('registrations', function ($query) use ($conference_id) {
                $query->where('conference_id', '=', $conference_id);
            })->get(); // use pluck('email') instead of get to select only email
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to instead of use the static value "1" in " $query->where('name', '=', 'rt1')" use "$request->rtype"? Because it appears undefined variable with $query->where('name', '=', $request->rype)". But also adding the $request->type to the use() like use($conference_id, $request->rtype)" it appears  "Expected: )".

Comment: @John see updated answer to use `$request` in closure function

Comment: And the query is returning an empty collection "Collection {#289 ▼
  #items: []
}".

Comment: In the conference model I have registrationTypes() instead of registration_types() like: "public function registrationTypes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
} " instead of "public function registration_types(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
} ". But changing to registration_types() also appears an empty collection.

Comment: @John Can you post the raw sql query generate by query builder by calling `toSql()` instead of `get()` lets see what query is produced, also unmark the answer as this isn't solved the issue yet

Comment: Thanks, its this: ""select * from `users` where exists (select * from `registrations` where `users`.`id` = `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` and exists (select * from `participants` where `registrations`.`id` = `participants`.`registration_id` and exists (select * from `registration_types` where `participants`.`registration_type_id` = `registration_types`.`id` and `name` = ? and `conference_id` = ?))) and exists (select * from `registrations` where `users`.`id` = `registrations`.`user_that_did_registration` and `conference_id` = ?)".

Comment: @John the query itself is correct i have tested it on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c82f0/1 using your sample data it is showing jake user , there must be some parameter /values issue for `$conference_id, $request`

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the issue is that in  your query there is "                $query->where('name', '=', $request->rype)" but the $request->rtype returns the id of the registration type, changing to name instead of id like "                $query->where('id', '=', $request->rype)"  works.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying wrong relationship names. Strings that you provide in `with()` method should match the relationship methods name on model. The correct way to eager load relationships is:

```
$getEmailsOfAspecificRegistrationType = Conference::with(
    'registrations.participants'
) ->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Also note that, you dont need to load each relation explicitly. When you eager load nested relationships, higher order relations are automatically loaded.

Comment: Thanks, but like that appears "Call to undefined relationship [registration_type] on model [App\Registration].".

Comment: Oops! Looks like you have participants relationship on registeration model. You can directly call this relationship on `registerations` whithout loading `registration_type`. I have updated my answer